# Error converting data type varchar to datetime. Stored procedure and two functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, datetime2

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_wl_CalculateWorklistItemGroupTypeCurrentStats, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 619]
Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

```
 exec sp_wl_CalculateWorklistItemGroupTypeCurrentStats @Practice_ID=20217,@WorkingDate='2022-06-02 14:59:04.4250000',@All=0
```

How can I handle this type of date WorkingDate?

What I have tried:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_wl_CalculateWorklistItemGroupTypeCurrentStats] (
  @Practice_ID bigint,
  @WorkingDate datetime = NULL,
  @All bit = 0
)
AS 

  SELECT 
    WLIT.WorklistItemGroupTypeIdentify as ID,
    WLIT.Name as Prefix, 
    dbo.fn_wl_CalculateWorklistItemGroupTypeCurrentLoad(@Practice_ID, WLIT.WorklistItemGroupTypeIdentify, @WorkingDate) as CurrentLoad,
    dbo.fn_wl_CalculateWorklistItemGroupTypeCurrentCapacity(@Practice_ID, WLIT.WorklistItemGroupTypeIdentify, @WorkingDate ) as MaxCapacity
  FROM WorklistItemGroupType WLIT
  WHERE WLIT.PracticeIdentify = @Practice_ID
  AND WLIT.ReportOn = CASE @All WHEN 1 THEN WLIT.ReportOn ELSE 1 END
```

The following is the first function expected to return **Currentload** results.  Which are numeric values.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_wl_CalculateWorklistItemGroupTypeCurrentCapacity] (
  @Practice_ID bigint,
  @GroupType_ID int,
  @WorkingDate datetime = NULL
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @GlobalCapacity int = 0, @DayCapacity int = 0, @InstanceCapacity int = 0, @Result int = -1

  IF ISNULL(@WorkingDate, -1) = -1
    SET @WorkingDate = GETDATE()

  SET @WorkingDate = CAST(@WorkingDate as DATE) --remove time from datetime

  -- get capacity
  SELECT @GlobalCapacity = W.MaxCapacity, 
    @DayCapacity = CASE (@@datefirst - 1 + datepart(weekday, @WorkingDate)) % 7
      WHEN 0 THEN SundayCapacity
      WHEN 1 THEN MondayCapacity
      WHEN 2 THEN TuesdayCapacity
      WHEN 3 THEN WednesdayCapacity
      WHEN 4 THEN ThursdayCapacity
      WHEN 5 THEN FridayCapacity
      WHEN 6 THEN SaturdayCapacity
    END,
    @InstanceCapacity = COALESCE(Ext.MaxCapacity, 0)
  FROM WorklistItemGroupType W
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 WLIGTIdentify, MaxCapacity
                   FROM WorklistItemGroupTypeExtension 
                   WHERE WLIGTIdentify = @GroupType_ID
                   AND @WorkingDate BETWEEN TargetDateStart AND TargetDateEnd) as Ext ON (W.WorklistItemGroupTypeIdentify = Ext.WLIGTIdentify)
  WHERE WorklistItemGroupTypeIdentify = @GroupType_ID
  AND PracticeIdentify = @Practice_ID

  IF @InstanceCapacity > 0
    SET @Result = @InstanceCapacity
  ELSE IF @DayCapacity > 0
    SET @Result = @DayCapacity
  ELSE IF @GlobalCapacity > 0
    SET @Result = @GlobalCapacity;

  RETURN @Result
END
```

The following is the second function. Is expected to return the current max capacity.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_wl_CalculateWorklistItemGroupTypeCurrentLoad] (
  @Practice_ID bigint,
  @GroupType_ID int,
  @WorkingDate datetime = NULL
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @CurrentLoad int = -1

  IF ISNULL(@WorkingDate, -1) = -1
    SET @WorkingDate = GETDATE()

  SET @WorkingDate = CAST(@WorkingDate as DATE) --remove time from datetime
  
  --get current load
  SELECT @CurrentLoad = COUNT(WLI.WorkListItemIdentify)
  FROM WorkListItem WLI
  INNER JOIN WorklistItemType WLIT ON (WLI.ItemTypeIdentify = WLIT.WorklistItemTypeIdentify) AND (WLIT.GroupTypeIdentify = @GroupType_ID)
  WHERE WLI.DateCreated BETWEEN @WorkingDate AND @WorkingDate + '23:59:59.997'
  AND WLI.PracticesIdentify = @Practice_ID
  AND WLI.Deleted = 0

  RETURN @CurrentLoad
END
```

Comment: Scalar functions are notoriously horrible for performance. You also have a top 1 with no order by in your first function. That is a sign that something is not quite right.  The second function has a MAJOR problem with the where predicates. You are passing in a datetime and then sticking a string on the end of it. That is never going to work.  Also using between with datetime values is often a problem. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: The string you are trying to pass in as a date - is formatted as a datetime2 data type.  That is going not going to work and will give you the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Too many `0`s on the end of the date literal. Remove them and you should be fine.

```
@WorkingDate='2022-06-02 14:59:04.425'
```

Also this:

```
WLI.DateCreated BETWEEN @WorkingDate AND @WorkingDate + '23:59:59.997'
```

should be this:

```
WLI.DateCreated >= @WorkingDate AND WLI.DateCreated < DATEADD(day, 1, @WorkingDate)
```

Finally, not a bug, but I'd reduce all of this:

```
IF ISNULL(@WorkingDate, -1) = -1
  SET @WorkingDate = GETDATE()

SET @WorkingDate = CAST(@WorkingDate as DATE) --remove time from 
datetime
```

Down to this:

```
Set @WorkingDate = CAST(COALESCE(@WorkingDate, current_timestamp) as Date)
```

Comment: or declare @WorkingDate as datetime2   Either way good eye  +1

Comment: @SeanLange I had the edit already in progress

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn This is the input I get from the application but it generates an error 

 I need to convert  this @WorkingDate='2022-06-02 14:59:04.4250000'  to  '2022-06-02 14:59:04.425' before script execute

Comment: Then fix the application. It's giving you a bad input.

Comment: Or change the parameter to datetime2 - and if the columns data type is datetime - cast/convert to a datetime data type.